# Can I put my macro define to config.h by using AC_XXXX_CONFIG syntax?

Tags: c, linux, autotools, automake

I know AC_SUBST(VAR) to pass the VAR to Makefile.am.

Are there any syntax to generate my #define into config.h in configure.ac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you use [AC_CONFIG_HEADERS](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Configuration-Headers) - e.g., `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])` in `configure.ac` - the [AC_DEFINE](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Defining-Symbols) macro will generate a `#define ...` in the header.